# Use Gunicorn With Nginx On Ubuntu Without Any Framework

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, web, gunicorn

I Have A Code That Runs Well With `gunicorn -b :8080 web:Main` In Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- Coding: UTF-8 -*-

def Main(env,start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    data = "<h1>It Works!</h1>"
    return data
```

Now I Want To Configure Nginx To Use Gunicorn To Serve Python Apps,I've Read The [Docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#nginx-configuration) But I Couldn't Understand How To Do That (So I Don't Need To Use gunicorn Command)

I Also Searched A Lot But All The Results Used Django,Flask And VirtualEnv.
What I Need Is "Python Web Development From Scratch" In Ubuntu.

Is It Possible To Do This Without Any Framework Or Is It Recommended?

Comment: This has nothing to do with frameworks. Whether you're using a framework or not, you still need to run gunicorn so that nginx can proxy to it.

Comment: first you have to run `Gunicorn` later you can run `Nginx`. It will connect to Gunicorn similar like web browser does - of course you have to configure Nginx to connect to Gunicorn on `localhost:8080`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks,that's what I want,How can I make Nginx to proxy it?

Comment: @furas thanks for your answe, how can I connect nginx to gunicorn?

Comment: you do it similar like in examples for flask or django - nginx doesn't know what code gunicorn is using.

Comment: I use `virtual-hosts` in nginx so I have something like this http://pastebin.com/4cc2vEKj in `/var/nginx/sites-available/wsgi-test` (and linked to `/var/nginx/sites-enabled/wsgi-test` ) . And I have `127.0.0.1 wsgi` in `/etc/hosts` to use name `wsgi` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I don't remember if I had to add something in `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` so I put this file too - see the same link. (maybe I had to add something in this file for PHP or other language or framework)

Comment: @furas thanks, should I replace '@gunicorn' by something else? (sorry I'm a little newbie)

Comment: you don't have to. But you can use `@hello_kitty` if you need it ;)

Comment: @furas thanks a lot! I get that <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I Did Is Came From The Help Of @furas And I Changed My Nginx Server Block (Virtual Host) Configuration Like [This Link](http://pastebin.com/4cc2vEKj) And Run The Gunicorn With The Port Of 3001 (You Can Change It) And It Worked!